# sorl-thumbnail not creating thumbnails

Tags: python, django, sorl-thumbnail

I'm having some difficulty with `sorl-thumbnail`.

My template is as follows:

```
{% thumbnail project.image "75x75" crop="center" as im %}
<img src="{{ im.url }}" width="{{ im.width }}" height="{{ im.height }}">
{% empty %}
<p>:(</p>
{% endthumbnail %}
```

In my rendered webpage I get the following path for the thumbnail:

`<img src="/media/cache/ff/29/ff299c50543aa807b0fbd28faf271e63.jpg" width="75" height="75">`

Now this all makes sense because my `MEDIA_URL` is set as `/media/` which is mapped in my apache `httpd.conf` to a local folder on my server.

The problem is that this path does not exist on the server so the image is displayed as a broken link.

It's worth noting I am using a custom storage object although this shouldn't affect things as it's passed straight through the `sorl.thumbnail ImageField`. Also I am using a `memcached` cache backend running on the server.

The annoying thing is that I don't get any errors even though I have `THUMBNAIL_DEBUG` and `DEBUG` on so it's difficult to see what's going wrong. I'm fairly sure it's failing to write the thumbnail files to disk but returning as successful because the `{% empty %}` statement doesn't get triggered and the appropriate cache files do not appear on the server. I don't know why though due to the lack of any error.

I'm kinda stuck at this point so any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

I've given up with sorl now and am using easy-thumbnails instead which is working fine.

Comment: Have you checked the actual folder on the server to see if the thumbnail has been successfully generated or is the thumbnail not being created at all? If there is no problem with the thumbnails being generated, it's probably an issue with your `MEDIA_URL` and `MEDIA_ROOT` settings or something similar

Comment: Yes. I have checked the folder on the server and the thumbnails are not being created. Unfortunately I'm not sure why. My `MEDIA_ROOT` and `MEDIA_URL` seem to be set up ok. They work in every other aspect of the site. ie. The `model.image.url` method returns the correct value.

Answer (score 3):

I have had very similar problem with you, I cannot use `easy-thumbnails` because I need to create thumbnails from external source. what I have figured out is on staging is using the same database as development, so after I rendered the images on development, it stores the cached filenames into database, and when you try to render on staging, it picks up the filenames from the same database, but obviously the files are not on staging.

Try running

```
./manage thumbnail clear
```

Comment: I can confirm it can be problem with memcached. The path to thumb is already in database but the thumb file is  not any more in filesystem. ./manage thumbnail clear didnt help to me. Had to clear database manually.

Answer (score 0):

Sorl did not create thumbnails for us because we used urls that were incorrectly encoded. They would contain '+' instead of ' ' or '%20' for spaces and sorl would re-encode them to '%2B' ('+' encoded). The resulting url error was suppressed and the thumbnail creation was ignored. Maybe it helps someone with this problem.